# Duplicate value of a field with respect to other field

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get duplicate value of a field with respect to other field.
duplicate value of RAP07C.SSISEQ on RAP07C.SSITYP

I used 'HAVING COUNT(RAP07C.SSISEQ) > 1' with respect to RAP07C.SSITYP, But I am getting the records if they have two or more records even though the two value of RAP07C.SSISEQ is same with respect to RAP07C.SSITYP. But I want records with the different value of RAP07C.SSISEQ.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  /*+ use_hash(RAP01 rap07a RAP07C) */
  Rap01.plcy,
  Rap01.j01_PT_LINE_cat_Cd AS j01_PT_LINE_cat_Cd,
  Rap01.J01_Pt_State_Cd    AS J01_Pt_State_Cd,
  COUNT(RAP07C.SSISEQ)     AS Count_of_SSISEQ,
  --RAP07C.SSISEQ,
  RAP07C.SSITYP
  --
FROM Rap01
  --
JOIN RAP07C
ON RAP07C.J41_PT_LINE_CAT_CD  = rap01.j01_pt_line_cat_cd
AND RAP07C.J41_PT_CDB_PART_ID = rap01.j01_pt_cdb_part_id
AND RAP07C.J41_PT_STATE_CD    = rap01.j01_pt_state_cd
AND RAP07C.PLCY               = rap01.plcy
AND RAP07C.dropdt_t           = '31-DEC-9999'
  --
WHERE Rap01.Line3 IN ('010','016')
GROUP BY RAP01.plcy,
  j01_PT_LINE_cat_Cd,
  J01_Pt_State_Cd,
  RAP07C.SSITYP
HAVING COUNT(RAP07C.SSISEQ) > 1;
```

I want different values of RAP07C.SSISEQ with respect to RAP07C.SSITYP
Like: IFS - 001 IFS - 001 as I got above two values 001 with respect to IFS, But I need to get only different values for IFS (RAP07C.SSITYP) as IFS - 001 IFS - 002.

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT here, your GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , I am getting records as                                                         SSITYP   SSISEQ                                                                                              CCI 001
IFS 002
CCI 001
IFS 002   , here I got same Value 001 with respect to CCI and 002 wrt IFS , But these value should be different.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @jarlh , IFS 001
IFS 001                    as I got above two values 001 with respect to IFS, But I need to get different values for IFS.

Comment: Hey, not as comments, edit your question instead!

Comment: @jarlh , I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the word DISTINCT inside the COUNT.

```
SELECT 
  Rap01.plcy,
  Rap01.j01_PT_LINE_cat_Cd AS j01_PT_LINE_cat_Cd,
  Rap01.J01_Pt_State_Cd    AS J01_Pt_State_Cd,
  COUNT(DISTINCT RAP07C.SSISEQ)     AS Count_of_SSISEQ,
  RAP07C.SSITYP

FROM Rap01

JOIN RAP07C
ON RAP07C.J41_PT_LINE_CAT_CD  = rap01.j01_pt_line_cat_cd
AND RAP07C.J41_PT_CDB_PART_ID = rap01.j01_pt_cdb_part_id
AND RAP07C.J41_PT_STATE_CD    = rap01.j01_pt_state_cd
AND RAP07C.PLCY               = rap01.plcy
AND RAP07C.dropdt_t           = '31-DEC-9999'

WHERE Rap01.Line3 IN ('010','016')
GROUP BY RAP01.plcy,
  j01_PT_LINE_cat_Cd,
  J01_Pt_State_Cd,
  RAP07C.SSITYP
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT RAP07C.SSISEQ) > 1;
```